# Regex: Find all links that doesn't have one / (slash)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

Suppose I have a link like this:

`https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/the-continuity-of-the-work-of-art.html`

How can I find all links (such as the one above) that doesn't have / (slash) after `/en`

**The Output:**

So, the regex should find all links such as:

`https://neculaifantanaru.com/enthe-continuity-of-the-work-of-art.html`

BUT NOT this kind of links:

`https://neculaifantanaru.com/azerbaijan.html`

So, only those that have `https://neculaifantanaru.com/en`

Comment: `^https:\/\/neculaifantanaru.com\/en([^\/]|$)` https://regex101.com/r/2mMKdD/1 or `^https:\/\/neculaifantanaru.com\/en(([^\/].*)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/2mMKdD/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex does the job:

```
https://\S+/en(?!/)\S*
```

**Explanation:**

```
https://        # literally
\S+             # 1 or more non space characters
/en             # literally
(?!/)           # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a slash after
\S*             # 0 or more non space characters
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/qmTpLs/1)

Answer (score 0):

I find another method:

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `https://neculaifantanaru\.com/en\w{1,}`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Be aware that will not match `https://neculaifantanaru.com/en`